# Question about the weak topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. The definition of the weak topology $\tau_w$ is that it is the weakest topology on $H$ such that all $\varphi \in H^\ast$ are continuous. It is a fact stated e.g. on Wikipedia that

A net $x_\lambda $ converges to $x$ in the weak topology if and only if $\varphi(x_\lambda) \to \varphi (x)$ for all $\varphi \in H^\ast$.

It is clear to me that if $x_\lambda \to x$ then $\varphi (x_\lambda) \to \varphi (x)$ because $\varphi$ is continuous (or at least I believe that this is true by using the sequence definition of continuity of a function).

What is not clear to me is the other direction:

> How to prove that if $\varphi(x_\lambda) \to \varphi (x)$ for all
>   $\varphi \in H^\ast$ then $x_\lambda \to x$ in the weak topology?

Answer (score 0):

First, we see that $x_\lambda$ converges weakly to $x$ **iff** $x_\lambda-x$ converges weakly to $0$. So, just deal with $x=0$ to simplify.

Sets of the form $B = \{ x | |\phi_k(x)| < \epsilon, k=1,...,n\}$ form a
base for weak neighbourhoods of $0$.

Suppose $\phi(x_\lambda) \to 0$ for all $\phi$. Let $W$ be a weak open set containing $0$.  There is some base element $B \subset W$ of the above form
for some $\phi_1,...,\phi_n$. Then
$ ( \phi_1(x_\lambda),...,\phi_n(x_\lambda) ) \to (0,...,0)$, hence
we have $x_\lambda \in B$ eventually. Hence $x_\lambda$ converges weakly to $0$.