# Weak topology net: $x_\alpha \rightarrow x $ iff $f(x_\alpha) \rightarrow f(x)$. Are open sets translation invariant?

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence, weak-topology

As described in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology),

> If $\langle x_\alpha \rangle $ is a net in vector space $X$ with the weak topology, then $x_\alpha \rightarrow x$ iff $\phi(x_\alpha) \rightarrow \phi(x)$ for all $\phi \in X^*$.

I am stuck on the converse. I found this [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166104/question-about-the-weak-topology) which I understood except the first line,

> we see that $x_\lambda$ converges weakly to $x$ **iff** $x_\lambda-x$ converges weakly to $0$.

---

*My thoughts:*
I think we need to show that open sets in $X$ are translation invariant - but I don't see how that is true in the weak topology.

Comment: To explain that line assume that $U$ is a weak-neighborhood of $x$. We can assume that we are in the case $U=\phi^{-1}(V)$. Then $U'=\phi^{-1}(V-\phi(x))$ is a neighborhood of $0$. A tail of the net $x_\lambda$ falling in $U$ is equivalent to the corresponding tail of $x_\lambda- x$ falling inside $\phi^{-1}(V-\phi(x))$. In fact, $x_i\in U=\phi(V)$ is equivalent to $\phi(x_i)-\phi(x)=\phi(x_i-x)\in V-\phi(x)$ and this is equivalent to $x_i-x\in \phi^{-1}(V-\phi(x))$.

Comment: What definition for the weak topology do you use?

Comment: Hellen, thanks, that makes sense. Clark, I use the definition as given in wikipedia.